# Change SoapClient options

Tags: php, soap

It is possible to pass `$options` to the constructor of `SoapClient`. But I don't find a way to change this options after object creation - during lifetime.

Questions:

- Is it possible to change the `"stream_context"` option for SoapClient?
- Is it possible to change any option of SoapClient?

... after the object has been created?

Code:

```
__construct($wsdl, $options);
                   // i want to change these options after object is created


class MySoapClient extends SoapClient {
    public function setOption($key, $value) {
        // how ?
    }
}

$sc = new MySoapClient($wsdl, $options);
$sc->setOption('steam_context', $my_stream_context);
```

In my case I need to change HTTP headers for every request. And I don't want to create new SoapClient object every single request.

Comment: @hek2mgl no, you read the manual. such functionality (if available) is not documented

Comment: Yep I see the problem now +1 ;)

Comment: You probably suffer from the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. No sane SOAP service will force you to set HTTP headers yourself. Describe your original problem, not your problem with the solution you think is appropriate.

Comment: @Sven: This is not XY Problem. My original problem is - i need to set HTTP Headers for different soap requests, exactly as I described. Just for your curiosity: [see HTTP Headers section](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/large-merchant-services/Concepts/MakingACall.html).

Comment: Yes, it is. Your original "X" problem is how to deal with the Ebay API! Your assumed solution is to use the PHP SoapClient, and your problem "Y" is how to only create one client and dynamically add HTTP headers - without mentioning any relations to Ebay. Not mentioning Ebay for example in your tags means that anybody who has expertise with Ebay API will NOT see your problem. And it really might be that the solution to deal with Ebay in PHP is NOT to use the SoapClient. Think about it, and then update your question accordingly.

Comment: @Sven: It is not. I want to change SOAP options an run time. It's quite simple question. I really know how to deal with ebay api (soapclient worked great so far for Ebay Trading API, Paypal and many more), I know how to make workarounds (and I did), I know i can use another libraries like NuSOAP etc. However my question was quite clear - is it possible to change SoapClient options at run time. I am not asking how to deal with ebay api. I just want straight answer "No, it is not possible with soapclient" or "Yes, ..."

Comment: @wahoo Where you able to change it? if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if You only need to change headers - check [this out](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php).
It should do exactly what You want, and as You can see, it is documented.